# Помогите починить Progressbar

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Progressbar не останавливается после того, как дошел до конца, а идет на новый круг.

Не понимаю как это исправить?

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import customtkinter as CTk
from PIL import Image


class CTkProgressbar(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self._value = tk.DoubleVar()
        self._value.set(0)

        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, variable=self._value, maximum=100.0, mode='determinate')
        self.progressbar.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True, padx=10)

    def start(self):
        self.progressbar.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.progressbar.stop()

    def set(self, value):
        self._value.set(value)


class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("500x550")
        self.title("MyApp")
        self.resizable(width=True, height=True)

        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue")

        self.numbers = ['X', 'X1.02', 'X4.68', 'X2.17', 'X26.56', 'X1.00','X2.86', 'X1.26', 'X17.11']
        self.current_index = 0

        self.frame_1 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self)
        self.frame_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10, fill="both", ipadx=10, ipady=10)

        custom_font = ("Helvetica", 60, "bold")
        self.label_1 = CTk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_1, text=str(self.numbers[self.current_index]), justify=CTk.LEFT,
                                    font=custom_font)
        self.label_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.progressbar_1 = CTkProgressbar(self.frame_1)
        self.progressbar_1.pack(pady=10, fill='both')

        self.button_1 = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.frame_1, text='Кнопка', command=self.button_callback)
        self.button_1.pack(pady=30, padx=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

        self.logo = CTk.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("fly.png"), size=(200, 200))
        self.logo_label = CTk.CTkLabel(master=self, text='', image=self.logo)
        self.logo_label.pack(ipady=10, ipadx=10, expand=1)

        self.lucky_jet_label = CTk.CTkLabel(master=self, text=" ", font=("Aria", 40, "bold"))
        self.lucky_jet_label.pack(pady=1)

    def button_callback(self):
        self.progressbar_1.start()
        self.after(6021, lambda: self.update_label())

    def update_label(self):
        self.progressbar_1.stop()
        self.current_index += 1
        if self.current_index >= len(self.numbers):
            self.current_index = 0
        number = self.numbers[self.current_index]
        self.label_1.configure(text=str(number))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

В твоем коде мне довольно трудно ориентироваться, но в классическом Tkinter есть функция `.update()`, попробуй её.

Comment: Она применяется к переменной всего окна